# Android SharedPreferences get drawable if value doesn´t exist

Tags: android, imageview, sharedpreferences, android-drawable

so in my app I need to save and to display an image on a image view, so i use SharedPreferences for saving it, the problem is that, if there is not a saved value, i want to display an image from drawables, and for that I´m using this code:

```
final ImageButton imgView = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.UserImageButton);
String photo = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(UserActivity.this).getString("Image", String.valueOf(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user, getApplicationContext().getTheme())));//NameOfTheString, StringIfNothingFound
        imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo));
```

But if there is no image saved, the drawable is not used on the ImageView, and it doesn´t show anything.
How could I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There's no requirement to use the default value of your `getString()` method as a direct path to your drawable. You could simply do the following:

```
private static final String IMAGE_PREF = "image_pref_key";
private static final String PREF_FAIL_CODE= "no_image_found";

String photo = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(UserActivity.this).getString(IMAGE_PREF, PREF_FAIL_CODE);

if (photo.equals(PREF_FAIL_CODE) {
    imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting the string from default shared preferences, if the value is not stored, set the default value returned to something e.g. `"not found"`

Now before setting doing `setImageBitmap` check if the value in your String variable `photo` is `"not found"`. If it is display the drawable from your resource. Else display your saved image after decoding it as your are doing it currently.